# Default arguments and SQL queries in Python - idioms / patterns?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I have many methods in my database model class which execute paramaterized SQL `SELECT` statements. Most of these queries include a `WHERE` clause with fields that filter the results. In the default case I want to ignore a comparison in the where clause to get all results. An example:

```
def get_notes(self, pcb_serial_no, note_type=None):
    ''' Get notes recorded against a PCB unit, optionally filtered by note_type. '''
    cursor = self.db.execute('''
        SELECT pcb_serial_no, note_type, description, username, note_time
        FROM pcb_notes_view
        WHERE pcb_serial_no=?
            AND COALESCE(?, note_type)=note_type
        ''',
        (pcb_serial_no, note_type,)
    )
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return len(rows) > 0 and rows
```

I'm using the combination of default argument value `None` (which maps to `NULL`) and `COALESCE`. This is the best solution I could think of so far for readability (subjective of course), but I'm sure this "default parameter" is a common requirement and wondered what idiomatic ways exists to implement it? I'm also not sure if there is a significant performance hit for the `COALESCE` in the default case, especially if that column is not indexed?

Comment: You could really benefit from an ORM like SQLAlchemy (`sqlalchemy.sql.select` and may be SQLSoup).

Comment: Hi Paulo. I'm not a fan of ORM so far. I've only used two of them but I don't like that they replace SQL (a dedicated language for writing relational queries) with somewhat clunky Python constructs to achieve the same effect. I know there are other benefits to be had, but I don't really want that level of abstraction of the underlying SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the comment system is not good for posting an example, but SQLAlchemy has a pretty much 1:1 mapping to raw SQL, and I find this approach better than composing statements from string manipulation. So this is more a comment than an answer, I hope you forgive me.

Rewriting your function ORM style would result something like:

```
def get_notes(self, pcb_serial_no, note_type=None):
    ''' Get notes recorded against a PCB unit, optionally 
        filtered by note_type. '''
    q = sql.select([
            pcb_notes_view.pcb_serial_no, 
            pcb_notes_view.note_type, 
            pcb_notes_view.description, 
            pcb_notes_view.username, 
            pcb_notes_view.note_time
        ]).where(
            pcb_notes_view.pcb_serial_no==pcb_serial_no
        )
    if note_type is not None:
        q = q.where(pcb_notes_view.note_type==note_type)
    rows = q.execute().fetch_all()
    return len(rows) > 0 and rows
```

Since the ORM makes reusing queries so easy, and the ORM can guess the relationship between tables (for databases with referential integrity), I tend to define ORM queries instead of views (mapping views from SQLSoup requires a bit more work). Combined with smart auto-complete from a good IDE (I use PyCharm) and I'm totally more productive with the ORM.

But it is a matter of taste. One could as well move all the logic to the database using stored procedures.

Comment: Hi Paulo. Thanks for taking the time to post a detailed example, and I think this is fine as an answer instead of a comment. I agree that this syntax is quite close to an actual SQL statement (compared to the ORMs I've tried). I'll look into SQLAlchemy in more detail and see how it handles JOINs and other SQL features. I'm upvoting you but I'm going to hold off for a bit before I accept :)